# How to add a second series in highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, html, highcharts

I have been trying to display the second value of my json file in highcharts for two days.

my json file:

```
[[1591518187000,17.3,12.7],[1591518135000,17.2,12.7]...[1591518074000,17.2,12.6],[1591518020000,17.2,12.7]]
```

The time and the first value are displayed correctly.

my script in php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var chart;
        function requestData() {
        $.getJSON('../****json.php', 
            function (data) {
                var series = chart.series[0];
                series.setData(data);
            }
        );
    }
    (document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                defaultSeriesType: 'line',
                marginRight: 10,
                marginBottom: 25,
                events: { load: requestData }
            },
       .....
                series: [{
                name: 'Temperatur',
                data: []

                },
                {
                name: "Taupunkt",
                    data: []
      ......    
</script>
```

Does anyone happen to have a way of drawing the second values ​​as a line?

Answer (score 0):

You could process your data and make two data sets for both series. Both data sets will have the same x values, but different y values. The code could look something like this:

```js
        $.getJSON('../****json.php', 
            function (data) {
                var dataSetOne = [],
                    dataSetTwo = [];
                data.forEach(function(point) {
                    dataSetOne.push([point[0], point[1]);
                    dataSetTwo.push([point[0], point[2]);
                });
                chart.series[0].setData(dataSetOne);
                chart.series[1].setData(dataSetTwo);
            }
        );
```

Comment: Thank you; I have now found this solution and it works great [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822923/retrieving-json-data-for-highcharts-with-multiple-series

Comment: Then this question is a duplicate of that question. Voted to close.